# Can I omit repeating things in も-sentences?

Tags: particle-も

This is an example taken from the Genki textbook. It's an exercise on using the particle も. It asks to translate the following sentence to Japanese:

```
Yui ate ice cream on Friday. She ate ice cream on Saturday, too.
```

Now, I can surely translate it literally without omitting anything unnecessarily:

```
ゆいさんは金曜日にアイスクリームを食べました。土曜日にもアイスクリームを食べました。
```

However, I am learning how to omit repeating things or things that are clear from the context in Japanese, as it is a bit different from how it works in the languages I know. *In the translation above, can I omit the word 'ice cream' in the second sentence?* So it would look like this:

```
ゆいさんは金曜日にアイスクリームを食べました。土曜日にも食べました。
```

*Would this shortening sound natural in Japanese?* I couldn't figure this out in Genki, neither could I find an answer online. Sorry if the question is trivial, I'm still getting a feel of this aspect of the language. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds fine to me. They both sound like perfectly acceptable textbook Japanese, and they both sound about as natural as the English does. (That is, to me, they all sound grammatically correct but rather clunky.)

Comment: @Billy, agree on the clunkiness, perhaps such sentences are just inevitable at such an early stage of learning a language. I guess I'm only worried about whether it's grammatically correct and acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think that's probably right!